# MongoDb Aggregate script which returns Top 10 per customer

Tags: mongodb

I have written a script which unwinds a transaction to line items and then aggregates by product along with summing quantity and total revenue of sales of the products. I then apply a sort by partyuuid (company) and itemTotalQuantity.

My question is, how do I make it so that per company, I get only the top 10 selling products? I have applied the sort so, per partyuuid I need only 10 products. Thanks

```
db.testCanonical.aggregate(
{ $match : {
   objectClass: "Goods & Services Transaction"
  ,objectCategory: "Sales"
  ,objectType: "Transaction"
//     , transactionDate.objectTransactionDate: {$gt: "2016-05-01T12:00:00.000Z", $lt: "2016-05-17T12:00:00.000Z"}
}
  },
{ $project: {_id: 1,partyuuid: 1,objectOrigin: 1,goodsAndServices: 1}},
{ $unwind: "$goodsAndServices" }
,
{$group: {
 _id: {
      partyuuid: "$partyuuid"
    , objectOrigin: "$objectOrigin"
    , itemName : "$goodsAndServices.itemName"
    }
    , "itemTotalQuantity":   {$sum: "$goodsAndServices.itemQuantity"}
    ,"itemGrossTotalValue": {$sum: "$goodsAndServices.itemTotalPrice"}
 }},
{
$project: {
    "_id":0,
    partyuuid: "$_id.partyuuid",
    itemName:"$_id.itemName",
    objectOrigin: "$_id.objectOrigin",
    itemTotalQuantity: "$itemTotalQuantity",
    itemGrossTotalValue: "$itemGrossTotalValue"
}
},
{$sort:{partyuuid: 1, itemTotalQuantity: -1}}
//,{$limit: 5}
//,{$out: "entity_datapoints"}
)
```

Let me know if you need a copy of a document which is being processed by this script. Thanks again

As per request, please see below for example Goods & Services Transaction which the above code works on.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5738fcff1a21db15b5c45b4b"),
"objectClass" : "Goods & Services Transaction",
"objectCategory" : "Sales",
"objectType" : "Transaction",
"objectOrigin" : "kounta",
"objectOriginCategory" : "Point of Sale",
"partyuuid" : "KountaPartyUUIDGoesHere",
"connectionuuid" : "5738fc661a21db15b5c45b49",
"objectTransactionDate" : ISODate("2016-05-16T04:03:56.201Z"),
"objectLastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-05-16T04:04:29.201Z"),
"objectCreationDate" : ISODate("2016-05-15T22:49:35.665Z"),
"statuses" : {
    "objectTransactionStatus" : "COMPLETE"
},
"goodsAndServices" : [ 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143460.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Cappuccino",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143460.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Cappuccino",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143460.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Cappuccino",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143460.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Cappuccino",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Espresso",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Espresso",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Espresso",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Espresso",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Flat White",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Flat White",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Flat White",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Long Black",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Macchiato",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 2.6099999999999999,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.3900000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Mocha",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "itemIdentifier" : 2143470.0000000000000000,
        "itemName" : "Mocha",
        "itemQuantity" : 1,
        "itemUnitNettPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTotalPrice" : 3.4800000000000000,
        "itemTaxTotal" : 0.5200000000000000
    }
],
"transactionGrossTotal" : 70,
"transactionTotalPayments" : 70,
"payments" : [ 
    {
        "paymentMethod" : "Cash",
        "paymentAmount" : 70,
        "paymentExtras" : 0,
        "paymentDate" : "2016-05-15T22:49:26+00:00"
    }
],
"party" : {
    "customer" : {},
    "staff" : {
        "staffid" : 53810
    }
},
"resources" : {
    "device" : {
        "deviceId" : 1031390.0000000000000000
    },
    "location" : {
        "locationId" : 25052
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sure, please add some sample documents and the expected output.

Comment: the expected output is, well, this one document has 20 items in it. I want it to limit to 10 items per document - not 10 records total. If you make two copies of the example document and run the script, I expect to see two sets of 10, thanks, Matt